# How to costum 'notEqual' in plugin jquery validation?

Tags: jquery

Here I want the notEqual function, which if the content of the input is not the same as 'HAMBURGER' or 'WATER' then validation will fail.

```
$.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
 return this.optional(element) || value != 'HAMBURGER' || value != 'WATER';
}, "This has to be different...");
```

I use the above code but the result fails, is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you entered is wrong, try this code, and correct your logic

```
$.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
 return this.optional(element) || value == 'HAMBURGER' || value == 'WATER';
}, "This has to be different...");
```